# Dynamically include meta data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, meta

I have configured routes like this:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/items/:category/', {
  templateUrl: 'items.html',
  controller: 'ItemsController',
  reloadOnSearch: false
})
.when('/items/item/:itemId/', {
  templateUrl: 'item.html',
  controller: 'ItemDetailController',
  reloadOnSearch: false
})
.otherwise({

});
```

First is for displaying all items, and the second is the detail view of one particular item.

And I have these meta data only for the detail view:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="product.item">
<meta property="og:product:retailer_item_id" content="[[ selectedItem.id ]]">
<meta property="og:product:condition" content="new">
<meta property="og:title" content="Товары магазина [[ selectedItem.shop.username ]]">
<meta property="og:image" content="[[selectedItem.img]]">
```

As all the views in angular views share one `<head>` tag, I want to include these meta tags dynamically, when a user chooses an item.

I thought I would do something like this:

```
<div ng-if="detailView" ng-controller="ItemDetailController">
    <meta property="og:type" content="product.item">
    // and the rest
</div>
```

It turned out that `<div>` is not allowed inside `<head>`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple Factory

```
angular.module('...').factory('SEO', function () {
  return {
    title: 'this is an amazing title',
    image: 'blablabla.png',
    ...
  };
});
```

and then you call it in your `.run()` method and then put it into $rootScope e.g. `$rootScope.seo = SEO;` then in your `<head>` tag you can write `$root.seo.title` and you just have to change SEO.title and SEO.image in your controller to update the `<head>` tag

I hope it will solve your problem,

do not hesitate to contact me if not :)

Comment: Hey. I was just wondering if this will be understood by the google crawlers? Will they see the title  as {{seo.title}} or the interpolated value? Would you know anything regarding this? else can you point me in a direction where I can figure this out?

Comment: Because google enable javascript on its robots, yes the robot will see the right title but you maybe need to write it in the robots.txt